# Error when run Rails server cloned from Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I cloned an app from Heroku, this app its working normally, but when I run it on Rails locally does not work. I need config some VAR?

I've the same RubyGem and Ruby version. But is not equal, here copy and paste Gem env LOCAL:
RubyGems Environment:

```
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/lala/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
     - /home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

And here is HEROKU gem env:

RubyGems Environment:

```
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
     - vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I don't know what more else I must set to work this app.

This is my database.yml

```
- development:
     - adapter: sqlite3
     - database: db/development.sqlite3
     - pool: 5
     - timeout: 5000

- test:
     - adapter: sqlite3
     - database: db/test.sqlite3
     - pool: 5
     - timeout: 5000

- production:
     - adapter: sqlite3
     - database: db/production.sqlite3
     - pool: 5
     - timeout: 5000
```

I cloned from Heroku, this app is wokring, but like I said, doesn't work locally.
I did: rake db:create AND  rake db:migrate, but the last I obtain this error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `translate_from_file' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0xaefad80>

/home/lala/rails_projects/wikasport/config/routes.rb:47:in `<top (required)>'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `reload_routes!'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:34:in `reload!'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:61:in `block in attach!'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__506550043__prepare__394196312__callbacks'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'

/home/lala/rails_projects/wikasport/config/environment.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'

/home/lala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

---

Here is routes.rb

AppDemo::Application.routes.draw do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

localized do
  .....
  .....
end

end

AppDemo::Application.routes.translate_from_file

---

Comment: What is not working?  Any exceptions or errors?

Comment: Edited with the error

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide at least database connection. It means that you have to create database.yml and configure it with your database.

Comment: Provide us config/route.rb, what is in the 47 line there?